# Erro de sintaxe em equação matemática (pyflakes E)

Tags: python, matemática, sintaxe, syntax-error

O código abaixo, escrito em python, apresenta erro de sintaxe na equação `Ff`. Busquei problemas relacionados ao fechamento dos parênteses, reescrevi a equação e ainda sim recebo a mensagem de erro. Ao passar o mouse sobre o identificador de erro no código aparece a mensagem  `Invalid syntax (pyflakes E)`.

```
import sympy
import math as m
E=210*10**9 
A=10**(-4)  
h=.1        
l=1.        
u=sympy.Symbol('u')

Ff=-2*E*A*((m.sqrt(((h-u)**2)-l**2)-m.sqrt((h**2)-l**2))(h-u)((h**2)*m.sqrt((h**2)-2*h*u+(l**2)+u**2)+(l**2)*m.sqrt((h**2)-2*h*u+(l**2)+u**2))m.sqrt((h**2)-l**2))/((h**6)-2*(h**5)*u+(h**4)*(u**2)+(l**2)*(h**4)-(l**4)*(h**2)+2*(l**4)*h*u-(l**6)-(l**4)*u**2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Python não consegue trabalhar com uma expressão desse tamanho, porém, você pode fraciona-la por partes em variáveis e juntar tudo depois.